# How to compare u'string' and 'string'?

Tags: python

I am trying to compare a key from a dictionary and a string.

```
if k == key:
   #do whatever
```

The repr(k) is u'string' while the key string I give it is 'string'. How can I get it so u'string' will equal 'string'?

Comment: You should do the opposite: convert `'string'` to a Unicode string. Use the [`unicode` constructor.](http://docs.python.org/howto/unicode.html)

Comment: Use Python 3, then you won't have to worry about that because all strings are Unicode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A direct comparison should work out of the box:

```
In [1]: u'string' == 'string'
Out[1]: True
```

Comment: your right, it would seem my error is somewhere else in my code. thanks

Comment: @zneak Gotta wait another 4 mins.